# How to configure 2 next.js apps on same proxy

Tags: next.js, proxy, reverse-proxy

So, I have 2 different next.js applications but the purpose is to run on the same URL, which currently is doing that. However, I have 2 different public folders and I want to use both, but when running the app when he tries to search for that image it alsos puts an /mce.

How can I configure the following proxyconfig to use both of the public?

```
upstream nextjs_upstream {\n\
    server ${FRONTEND_URL_CIP}:${FRONTEND_PORT};\n\
    server ${FRONTEND_URL_MCE}:${FRONTEND_PORT};
}\n\
upstream nextjs_upstream_cip {\n\
    server ${FRONTEND_URL_CIP}:${FRONTEND_PORT};\n\
}\n\
upstream nextjs_upstream_mce {\n\
    server ${FRONTEND_URL_MCE}:${FRONTEND_PORT};\n\
}\n\
\n\
server {\n\
    gzip on;\n\
    ${SSL_BLOCK}\n\
    server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;\n\
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;\n\
\n\
    location /_next/static {\n\
        proxy_cache STATIC;\n\
        proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;\n\
        add_header X-Cache-Status \$upstream_cache_status;\n\
    }\n\
\n\
    location /public {\n\
        proxy_cache STATIC;\n\
        proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;\n\
        proxy_cache_valid 60m;\n\
        proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;\n\
        add_header X-Cache-Status \$upstream_cache_status;\n\
    }\n\
\n\
    ${APIGW_BLOCK}\n\
\n\
    location / {\n\
        proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream_cip;\n\
    }\n\
    location /cip {\n\
        proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream_cip;\n\
    }\n\
    location /mce {\n\
        proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream_mce;\n\
    }\n\
}\n" | tee /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf;
```